# DataBinding with Dictionary indexer

Tags: c#, dictionary, mvvm, data-binding, win-universal-app

I'm new to UWP and MVVM.

And I have some trouble with DataBinding.

I have a property

```
public System.DayOfWeek CurrentDayOfWeek
```

and a dictionary

```
public MyDictionary Dictionary<System.DayOfWeek,List<String>>
```

I want to bind a ListView's ItemSource to MyDictionary[CurrentDayOfWeek]

Here's what I've struggled:

ViewModel:

```
public Dictionary<System.DayOfWeek,List<string>> MyDictionary
{
    get;set;
}
public System.DayOfWeek CurrentDayOfWeek {get;set;}
public List<System.DayOfWeek> DayOfWeeks {get;set;}
.....
```

XAML:

```
    <ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDayOfWeek,Mode=TwoWay}"
    <ListView ItemSource="{Binding MyDictionary[CurrentDayOfWeek]}"
    >
```

And this is not working.

I have to add a few additional property to my viewmodel to get this working as a work around,but I think it's too ugly.

I am Wondering if there're any elegant solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An "elegant solution" is highly opinionated, to me the most elegant solution is the one that works!

Comment: Dictionaries suck for binding.  Do NOT used them.  If you need to index in your binding (you shouldn't, if you think you have to, refactor), create a collection extending KeyedCollection<K,V>.  You can be slick and implement INotifyCollectionChanged to have a bindable indexed collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to show *key* of the dictionary in combobox and then **Binding ElementName** will give you *selected* in combobox item to define ListView binding.

```
                <ComboBox x:Name="DropDown"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.CurrentDayOfWeek}"
                   DisplayMemberPath ="Key"
                   SelectedValuePath ="Value"
                   IsReadOnly="True"></ComboBox>

                <ListView x:Name="List"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName = DropDown, Path = SelectedValue}"
                   DisplayMemberPath ="Value"
                   SelectedValuePath ="Value"/>
```